# Can `conv.ovf.u8.un` throw `OverflowException`?

Tags: .net, cil

I am working on an interpreter of CIL and came across `conv.ovf.u8.un`.

Making a test, I realized that even if `0xffffffffffffffff` is on the stack, `conv.ovf.u8.un` still doesn't throw `OverflowException`.

The following code:

```
ldc.i8 0xffffffffffffffff
conv.ovf.u8.un
box [mscorlib]System.UIntPtr
callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

works well, without an exception.

In general, it seems to be expected. But the ECMA-335 says:

> Convert unsigned to an unsigned int64 (on the stack as int64)
> and throw an exception on overflow.

That's why I decided to ask the community whether a case when `conv.ovf.u8.un` throws `OverflowException`.

Comment: @HansPassant: the opcode will never produce an overflow in the specific case of converting an i8, as the value is assumed to be unsigned and will always fit. You can make it overflow by putting something like a negative or too large floating-point value on the stack, though. The C# compiler won't generate opcodes for such a direct conversion as it will never assume a floating-point value is unsigned and inject a `conv.ovf.u8` conversion first (which will be the one that throws), but it's allowed on the IL level.